# How do I start a conversation with a friend I had a crush on in junior high?

Tags: conversations, online-interaction, making-friends, acquaintances

**Backstory:**

I met the person when I went to tuitions during my high school junior year. We didn't explicitly talk to each other as I was really shy but had some small talk here and there. As I didn't use any social media then, I didn't connect with the person on facebook. Her behavior towards me always irked me as she would always try to be nice to me or would join in on a conversation I was having with another person. She would also always try to sit next to me but I couldn't take the hint that she liked me. I couldn't start a conversation with her as I thought that she was way out of my league and thought that she was just messing with me in front of her friends.

So the days went by and towards the end of junior high, she told me that she would change the tuition place after the final exams. Sometime before the finals she took my register and wrote something along the lines of "better luck next time" on the back. I still don't know what she meant by this but at that point in time, I thought that I had blown my chance with the person.

We all became quite busy with studies and she changed tuitions after the exams. We never had any contact after that and it's been almost 6 years.
Fast-forward now, I've successfully completed my bachelors and will start work next month. I was reminiscing about my previous interactions and relationships with people and this relationship is the only thing I regret not pursuing. I'm not sure if she will remember me but I still wanna contact her in some way to get some closure. I searched around on the inter-webs and found her social media.

So my question is this " ***How do I start the conversation with that person without coming off as creepy*** " OR " ***How do I strike a conversation with the person after many years of no contact*** "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something similar happened to me a while back, when I was going to another school as well.
I had a friend and he left. I had no cell phone or anything back then, so I wasn't able to contact him.

Some years later I got his contact info from a person that knew him as well.
After thinking about it pretty much the same way as you: "How do I strike a conversation with a person after so many years?"

Well, I went with something of the lines of this:

> "Hi, I'm not sure if you remember me, but we went to xxx school
>   together, and I just got your contact info from yyy. I didn't have a
>   phone back then, that's why you couldn't give it to me that time.
>   Well, I was very happy to get the chance to write you another message
>   after all this time, and if you don't mind I would like to try and
>   keep in touch again?"

He responded after some time and we are friends again.
I don't know if this applies to the person you love as well, but I think you should give it a shot in any way.

Personally, I think it would just be good to tell, who you are and that you want to be friends (again) or something similar. I have never in my life met one person who was offended or creeped out by something like this.

In any way, I wish you the best of luck.